# Lost window title bars and everything after selecting bad window theme in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, theme

I've selected a window theme from the "Advanced Settings" in Linux Mint 12 which seems to be corrupted and I've lost everything on my desktop. I can't start any applications but I can open the terminal by right clicking on the desktop and selecting "Open in Terminal".

It would help me much if you can answer only one of the two questions bellow:

- How to start the "Advanced Settings" from the console?
- How to revert to the default window theme using the console?

Please keep in mind that I've got the problem when I changed the "Window Theme" not the "Shell Theme" in the Themes tab in the "Advanced Settings"

Comment: Which desktop manager is this, gnome?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default Linux Mint, you're using the [GNOME](http://www.gnome.org) Desktop Environment and you should be able to bring up the settings app with this command:

```
gnome-control-center
```

Once there, change your theme back to a working one.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to start the "Advanced Settings" program with the gnome-tweak-tool command.